# Неизвестная конструкция языка в Javascript которую использует Google

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular4, angular

Изучаю исходники механизма changeDetaction в angular6 и наткнулся на интересную конструкцию которая ни мне ни парням с работы не известна, вот  [ссылка на часть кода](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6b79ab5abec8b5a4b43d563ce65f032990b3e3bc/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L160), скажите может кто знает что это такое и как оно работает. Интересует строка 160;

```
let changes: SimpleChanges = undefined !;
```

Попытки воспроизвести код ничего мне не принесли

```
ngOnInit() {
let a = {
  a: undefined,
  b: {
    b: 'hello',
    c: 'mellow'
  },
  c: 'tribes'
};

const msg = (a !.b) !;
console.log(msg); // {b: "hello", c: "mellow"}
}
```

Comment: [Use the Google, Luke!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42273853)

Answer (score 4):

Это не оператор инверсии, а оператор `not-null` утверждения.
Оператор подсказывает компилятору, что тип операнда `не-null` и `не-undefined`, когда компилятор сам не может определить тип, поэтому не нужно `throw` ошибки что `value can be null or undefined here`.
Этот оператор нужно использовать, когда включен параметр компилятора `strictNullChecks`:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true
    }
}
```

Создаем какой-то файл `test.ts`:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    a: number;
    b?: number;
}

let someObject: SomeInterface | null = null;

someObject = {
    a: 1
};

console.log(someObject.a); // здесь будешь ошибка `someObject can be null`

console.log(someObject !.a); // а здесь нет
```

Comment: @Mr.Flance, если ответ Вас устроил, то примите его (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Тайп скрипт довольно успешно пытается быть строготипизированным языком, но отовсюду торчат уши js, видимо он и заставляет разработчика делать такую избыточность синтаксиса с точки зрения изначально строготипизированного ЯП такого как c#