# Зачем создавать объект в сигнатуре метода TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Объясните что означает синтаксис в TypeScript, когда внутри скобок `(opts: {onlySelf?: boolean} = {})` что происходит в данном участке когда, не могу понять как, му тут создаем безымянный объект с одной переменной типа boolean внутри?
В чем преимущество такого подхода? Почему не сделать проще и использовать переменную?

```
  markAsTouched(opts: {onlySelf?: boolean} = {}): void {
    (this as{touched: boolean}).touched = true;

    if (this._parent && !opts.onlySelf) {
      this._parent.markAsTouched(opts);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Потому что это сейчас в функции используется одна-единственная опция. А через полгода разработки их может быть уже пара десятков.

Comment: @Yaant, это то тут причем если это всего лишь параметры по умолчанию?

Comment: @overthesanity Да, но человек спрашивает, зачем для этого нужен объект с единственным полем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на ваш вопрос `Почему не сделать проще и использовать переменную?` следующим образом - `{ onlySelf?: boolean }` является уникальным параметром, параметры можно передавать в разные методы `FormGroup` и `FormControl`, но по сути мы используем методы `AbstractControl`, потому что от этого класса все наследуются. Представьте себе такого рода форму:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('Артур', {
        validators: [
            Validators.required
        ]
    }),

    lastName: new FormControl('Фамилия', {
        validators: [
            Validators.required
        ]
    })
});
```

Сейчас форма валидна:

```
log(this.form.valid === true); // true
```

Если мы изменим значение какого-то контрола на `null`:

```
this.form.get('name') !.setValue(null);
```

То естественным образом форма станет невалидной:

```
log(this.form.invalid === true); // true
```

Если же использовать параметр `onlySelf`:

```
this.form.get('name') !.setValue(null, {
    onlySelf: true
});
```

То изменится валидность только контрола, но не самой формы:

```
log(this.form.valid === true); // true
log(this.form.get('name') !.invalid === true); // true
```

`setValue` принимает и другие свойства в объекте `options`:

```
setValue(value: any, options: {
    onlySelf?: boolean,
    emitEvent?: boolean,
    emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
    emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
  } = {}): void
```

Этот параметр `options` передается по цепочке снизу вверх, потому что `FormGroup` это дерево, точно также и с методом `markAsTouched`, `setValue` вызывает метод `updateValueAndValidity` куда параметром передает `options`, `updateValueAndValidity` в свою очередь делает проверку значения на валидность и вызывает `markAsTouched` на контроле, куда также параметром передает эти опции, а теперь представьте если бы вместо объекта использовалась обычная переменная - была бы энтропия.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сорри за офтоп, а зачем тут восклицательный знак this.form.get('name') !.setValue(null); ?

Comment: `not-null` утверждение, возвращаемое значение метода `get` - `AbstractControl | null`

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865585/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-google/865598#865598

Comment: это параметр можно сравнить с DataTransferObject если я верно понял?

Comment: простите, не знаю что такое DataTransferObject в данном контексте, возможно это и так, но никогда не встречал, чтобы DTO использовался где-то в доке angular

Comment: вроде в java есть такое понятие, когда объект не имеет поведения а имеет только какие-то данные.