# Валидация полей формы по условию?

Tags: angular2, angular5, angular

У меня определены следующие парвила валидации для полей формы:

```
this.fb.group({
      'country': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'period_time': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'day': ['', [Validation.ruleLeaveValidator]],
      'month': ['', [Validation.ruleLeaveValidator]],
      'year': ['', [Validation.ruleLeaveValidator, Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.min(1920), Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]]
    });
```

Где, `Validation.ruleLeaveValidator` - кастомное правило валидации:

```
static ruleLeaveValidator(control: FormControl) {

    if (!control || !control.root['controls']) {
      return null;
    }

    if (control.root['controls']['period_time'].value == RuleLeaveEnum.DATE) {
      return !control.value || control.value == '' ? {'invalidPhoneNumber': true} : null;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Правило такое, если значение поля `period_time == RuleLeaveEnum.DATE` - тогда обязатьны для заполнения поля: day, month, year. В противном случае - они не обязательны к заполнению.

Мой код не сработал...

Полный код:

```
this.step4 = this.fb.group({
      country: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
          Validators.required
        ]
      }),

      period_time: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
          Validators.required,
          (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
            const {value} = control;

            const day = this.step4.get('day');
            const month = this.step4.get('month');
            const year = this.step4.get('year');

            if (value === RuleLeaveEnum.DATE) {
              day.setValidators([
                Validators.required
              ]);

              month.setValidators([
                Validators.required
              ]);

              year.setValidators([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(4),
                Validators.min(1920),
                Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
                Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
              ]);
            } else {
              day.setValidators(null);
              month.setValidators(null);
              year.setValidators([
                Validators.maxLength(4),
                Validators.min(1920),
                Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
                Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
              ]);
            }

            day.updateValueAndValidity();
            month.updateValueAndValidity();
            year.updateValueAndValidity();

            return null;
          }
        ]
      }),

      day: new FormControl(null),

      month: new FormControl(null),

      year: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
          Validators.maxLength(4),
          Validators.min(1920),
          Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
          Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
        ]
      })
    });
```

Второй вариант - это установка валидации динамически - прослушивая поле:

```
 this.step4.get('period_time').valueChanges.subscribe(
      (period: string) => {

        if (period === RuleLeaveEnum.DATE) {
          this.step4.get('day').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1}$')]);
          this.step4.get('month').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1}$')]);
          this.step4.get('year').setValidators([Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.min(1920), Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]);

        } else {

          this.step4.get('day').setValidators([]);
          this.step4.get('month').setValidators([]);
          this.step4.get('year').setValidators([]);
        }

        this.step4.get('day').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.step4.get('month').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.step4.get('year').updateValueAndValidity();

      });
```

Только вопрос, как сбросить валидатор если `period != RuleLeaveEnum.DATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вышло довольно громоздко, но тут нет ничего сложного:

```
public form = this.fb.group({
    country: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
            Validators.required
        ]
    }),

    period_time: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
            Validators.required,
            (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
                const { value } = control;

                const day = this.form.get('day') !;
                const month = this.form.get('month') !;
                const year = this.form.get('year') !;

                if (value === RuleLeaveEnum.DATE) {
                    day.setValidators([
                        Validators.required
                    ]);

                    month.setValidators([
                        Validators.required
                    ]);

                    year.setValidators([
                        Validators.required,
                        Validators.maxLength(4),
                        Validators.min(1920),
                        Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
                        Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
                    ]);
                } else {
                    day.setValidators(null);
                    month.setValidators(null);

                    year.setValidators([
                        Validators.maxLength(4),
                        Validators.min(1920),
                        Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
                        Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
                    ]);
                }

                day.updateValueAndValidity();
                month.updateValueAndValidity();
                year.updateValueAndValidity();

                return null;
            }
        ]
    }),

    day: new FormControl(null),

    month: new FormControl(null),

    year: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
            Validators.maxLength(4),
            Validators.min(1920),
            Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
            Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
        ]
    })
});
```

Я так и не понял, что делает ваша функция `ruleLeaveValidator`, поэтому я ее просто убрал, она по сути тут не нужна, нужно просто добавить валидатор к полю `period_time`, если значение равно `RuleLeaveEnum.DATE`, то мы к контролам `day, month, year` добавляем валидаторы, если нет, то убираем, в конце обновляем состояние через `updateValueAndValidity`.

Либо же можно вообще обойтись без валидатора и слушать изменение значения контрола, результат тот же:

```
public form = this.fb.group({
    country: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
            Validators.required
        ]
    }),

    period_time: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
            Validators.required
        ]
    }),

    day: new FormControl(null),

    month: new FormControl(null),

    year: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
            Validators.maxLength(4),
            Validators.min(1920),
            Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
            Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
        ]
    })
});

private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form.get('period_time') !.valueChanges.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe((value) => {
        const day = this.form.get('day') !;
        const month = this.form.get('month') !;
        const year = this.form.get('year') !;

        if (value === RuleLeaveEnum.DATE) {
            day.setValidators([
                Validators.required
            ]);

            month.setValidators([
                Validators.required
            ]);

            year.setValidators([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(4),
                Validators.min(1920),
                Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
                Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
            ]);
        } else {
            day.setValidators(null);
            month.setValidators(null);

            year.setValidators([
                Validators.maxLength(4),
                Validators.min(1920),
                Validators.max(new Date().getFullYear() + 20),
                Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
            ]);
        }

        day.updateValueAndValidity();
        month.updateValueAndValidity();
        year.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Comment: Это для версии Angular 2? может что-то есть готовое в 5 версии?

Comment: вы о чем? реактивные формы не изменились с момента выхода angular 2, поведение одинаковое на всех версиях

Comment: @Jony, если вам ответ не помог - напишите что у вас не получается, зачем задавать вопрос если вы не заинтересованы в поиске ответа?

Comment: Я не могу получить доступ внутри к `this.form.get('day')` - так как form еще не готова на этот момент. Можете отредактировать код? я приму ваше решение.Спасибо

Comment: И что означает знак ! в конце `const day = this.get('day') !`?

Comment: Я добавил в воппрос полный листинг - основываясь на вашем примере

Comment: @Jony, знак `!` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865585/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-google/865598#865598

Comment: @Jony, я добавил 2 варианта ответа, на случай если не сработает первый, попробуйте второй и скажите результат

Comment: Я обновил мой вопрос - что скажете? только не пойму как сбрасывать валидацию в противном случае

Comment: используя второй вариант с `valueChanges`- вам нужно убрать валидаторы, смотрите в мой пример, если я правильно понял то в случае `period === RuleLeaveEnum.DATE` валидаторов на `day | month | year` вообще быть не должно, уберите их просто из формы

Comment: Наоборот если `RuleLeaveEnum.DATE` - тогда валидируем только day/month,year.

Comment: в любом случае уберите их из формы, они у вас все равно вручную ставятся в потоке `valueChanges`